# How to display child categories only last updated post?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have categories list like

Designtype

```
Multi
    Sub cat multi 1
    sub cat multi 2
Borring
    Jall
    Daman
    Dupatta
    top parsi
Sequence
Trapping
```

i want to display onl last post of the jall damna dupatta and top parsi

Comment: Is this an array, database table or from a newspaper?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your post means. Did you switch to a different language toward the end? Either way, I think this function will be of use to you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories

Comment: in wordpree when we add the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$cat = get_categories();
echo “<pre>”;
//print_r($cat);
for each ($cat as $c)
{
if($c->cat_name == “Boring”)
{

$sub_cat = $c->term_id;
$cat2 = get_categories();

for each ($cat2 as $c2)
{

if($c2->parent == $sub_cat)
 {

echo “<pre>”;
echo $c2->cat_name;
echo “<br/>”;
 $aaaaaaaaaaaaaa =  query_posts(array(‘category_name’ => $c2->cat_name, ‘posts_per_page’ => 1 ));
print_r($aaaaaaaaaaaaaa);

} } } }
```

?>